# paper-drawer-toggle from the <i> with fa is not toggling (cell phone mode) - only on the page that includes an adjacent paper-slideshow

Tags: polymer, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia with Polymer. My app.html contains the navigation. The "i" tag is on line 50. link to code: 
https://github.com/IntegratedControls/LibraryFrontEnd/blob/dev/src/app.html

```
    <div main class="main-content">
  <i style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top:4px" class="fa fa-bars pull-left fa-2x" paper-drawer-toggle aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

The home.html contains the polyer-slideshow
https://github.com/IntegratedControls/LibraryFrontEnd/blob/dev/src/home.html

```
<polymer-slide>
  <paper-card class="slideshowimage" image="../styles/imgs/books1.jpg"></paper-card>
</polymer-slide>
<polymer-slide>
  <paper-card class="slideshowimage" image="../styles/imgs/books2.jpg"></paper-card>
</polymer-slide>
<polymer-slide>
  <paper-card class="slideshowimage" image="../styles/imgs/books3.jpg"></paper-card>
</polymer-slide>
```

Each page displays within the "router-view" "/router-view" that is in app.html (line 51)

Please help, thank you

Comment: Please make sure to include relevant parts of your code here, to get your answer more accurately/quickly. You can still leave the links, in case answerers need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Josh Storo for this solution, using the z-index:

```
<i style="z-index:10000000;position:relative;padding-left: 6px; padding-top:4px" class="fa fa-bars pull-left fa-2x" paper-drawer-toggle aria-hidden="true"></i>
```